# stddef.h is included but max_align_t is undeclared

Tags: c, gcc, c11

I want to compile this code:

```
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
int main ( int argc , char ** argv )
{
    printf ("%zu\n", alignof ( max_align_t ));
    return 0;
}
```

But compiler says that:

```
error: ‘max_align_t’ undeclared".
```

`stddef.h` is included and everything must be ok, isn't it?

P.S. I already tried to compile this code under gcc4.8 and gcc4.9, but I have error as described.

Comment: did you try compiling with `-std=c11`?

Comment: Yes, [max_align_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/max_align_t) is included in `stddef.h` since C11

Comment: Compiles fine here (gcc 4.7.2 using `-std=c11`)

Comment: Thanks for all of us. Everything is work now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a C11 feature you need to tell the compiler to run in C11 compliant mode.

For gcc this can be achieved by specifying the option `-std=c11`.

Comment: Thank you. But It is interesting: "Why compiler, for example in c99 mode, can't do the same job as a compiler in c11 mode?" In my opinion compiler in c99 mode can successfully go to the stddef.h and found there definition of max_align_t. Can somebody explain me: "What is wrong in this opinion?"

Comment: If you go to your `stddef.h` yourself and look for the definition of `max_align_t` it will become clear.

Comment: @andrei-volkau, for C99, the identifier `max_align_t` is not reserved, so using it is an intrusion in the user name space. It is only C11 that reserves it.

Comment: More recent versions of gcc use `-std=gnu11` by default (C11 with GNU extensions). Use `-std=c11` if you want to be sure that C11-specific features are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I use a compiler that is natively based on c99 that has a stddef.h that it uses. On my computer I need to use the -std=c11 option and also a header file that apparently corresponds to c11.

Comment: I don't believe this adds any information that isn't already in the accepted answer.